# Modify all values found by xPath Expression in huge xml file with VTD-XML and Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, vtd-xml

after a lot of research on the web, I decided to use the Java Api VTD-XML for combining huge xml files, parsing and editing, and xPath

The XML Files to modify are 10 MB - 400 MB and look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-9"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Scheme.xsd">
<Book>
    <BookInfo>
        <Novel>
            <NovelTitle>abc</NovelTitle>
            <Author>def</Author>
            <Address>
                <LastName>ghi</LastName>
                <FirstName>jklm<FirstName>
            </Address>
            <Address>
                <LastName>opqr</LastName>
                <FirstName>stuv</FirstName>
            </Address>
            <Customer>
                <CustomerNumber>1000</CustomerNumber>
                <Address>
                    <LastName>wxy</LastName>
                    <FirstName>zzzz</FirstName>
                </Address>
                <Address>
                    <LastName>aaaaa</LastName>
                    <FirstName>bbbb</FirstName>
                </Address>
            </Customer>
            .
            .
            .
        </Novel>
    </BookInfo>
</Book>
```

Please don't start a discussion about structure and element names. I can't change that.

I want to edit the elements values of ALL occurrences in the File that match a certain xPath Expression.
When I use VTD XML and XPath for that, in the resulting document only one element value is changed correctly.
My Code:

```
    static VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
static String inFile = "books.xml";
static XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    getNodesFromDocument();
}

private static void getNodesFromDocument() throws ParseException, NavException, XPathParseException, XPathEvalException, Exception {
    int result;
    AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot();
    ap.selectXPath("//Address[LastName='ghi']/FirstName/text()");
    if (vg.parseFile(inFile,true)){
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        ap.bind(vn);
        while((result = ap.evalXPath())!=-1){

            //System.out.println(vn.getText() + vn.toString(result));
            modifyNodes(vn, result);

        }
    }
    xm.output(new FileOutputStream("resultbooks.xml"));

}

private static void modifyNodes(VTDNav vn, int line) throws Exception{
    // instantiate VTDGen and XMLModifier
    xm.bind(vn);
        // update the text content

        if (line!=-1){
            xm.updateToken(line,"TestValue");
        }
}
}
```

I want to edit all values of //Address[LastName='ghi']/FirstName/text() in the Document, so

```
jkl
.
.
.
```

The while loop in getNodesFromDocument() shows all values correctly, but not all are modified. Just one

```
                    <LastName>ghi</LastName>
                <FirstName>TestValue<FirstName>
```

occurs in the output File. Can You help me to find a solution for the problem? Whats wrong in the code? Why is there only one modified value in the output?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you are giving just one XPath so that XPath only getting modified. you can most probably iterate over it to have various XPaths.

Comment: And do you know, how to do that with vtd-xml?

Comment: I would like to post an answer with the solution and another question, but it is not possible

Comment: With Saxon 9.6 EE you could use XSLT 3.0 and streaming to process and transform very large documents, would you be interested in that approach?

Comment: why do you declare XMLModifier to be static? That is somewhat strange?

Answer (score 2):

The reason textValue appear only once is because XMLModifier's bind does a lot of initialization and state cleaning that it actually wipes out any update/removal taking place prior... what you need to do is to not bind it every time in your private method "modifyNode," and instead moves the bind into the main... it will work ... see my code below

```
 static VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
 static String inFile = "c:\\xml\\kepler.xml";
 static XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier();

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, NavException, XPathParseException, XPathEvalException, Exception{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     int result;
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot();
        ap.selectXPath("//Address[LastName='ghi']/FirstName/text()");
        if (vg.parseFile(inFile,true)){
            VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
            ap.bind(vn);xm.bind(vn);
            while((result = ap.evalXPath())!=-1){

                //System.out.println(vn.getText() + vn.toString(result));
                xm.updateToken(result,"TestValue");

            }
        }
        xm.output(new FileOutputStream("c:\\xml\\resultbooks.xml"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is working. The next goal is, to implement that for all files from a filelist and additionally for all xPath Expressions from a given list. Do you know how to implement that? What do I have to consider using vtd xml?

Comment: I found out, how to do that. Base is vtd-xml authors solution. It is important, where you bind vn to xm. Thank you!